# JHipster Run Again But Failed

Tags: entity, liquibase, jhipster, gradlew

Yeserday I was creating jhipster and create entity (Author and Book) same as tutorial and run perfectly, but however today I run again (using gradlew bootRun) but the result is blank, the command is run without error, but the page is blank (only shows footer) . Please somebody help me to resolve my problem?
[image: the first looking command, could not find specific ehcache for Books, Author, Author Books]
the first looking command, could not find specific ehcache for Books, Author, Author Books

[image: after adding ehcache.xml for Book, Author, and Author.books but still remain blank page]
after adding ehcache.xml for Book, Author, and Author.books but the result still remain blank page

[image]

Comment: In the future, your question will be easier to read and to search for if you put the code/output in as text rather than pasting in pictures of text.

Comment: oke @SteveDonie, thanks fo the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've started grunt using `grunt serve`, or the equivalent command for gulp if you're using that.

Open up your web console using `F12` and check for any "resource not found" errors. If you see a lot of errors, try deleting your `bower_components` folder then rerunning `bower install`.

The ehcache warnings can be safely ignored.

Comment: after re-trying and comment-uncomment file app.js (for angular.module('mwadmin6App', [])) and index.html for bower_components declaration, now the application is run perfectly.

Comment: That's great! I didn't see your other comment because it was an "answer", next time you should reply to the answer directly so the other user will get notified.

Comment: because the character is not enough as a comment, so I put as an answer